# Ckeck if list of Uid are already inside the database Firebase ( Android )

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

Hello I create a small social network for my high school and I use android studio and firebase as server for the data.My database structure for Users info `- / (Users)
-   /James/
–-    /james-uid/
-   /David/
–-    /james-uid/`

I added the possibility of blocking users. My database is structured

`- / (root)
-   /UsersIblocked/
–-    /james-uid/
--    /jake-uid/
--   /David-uid/
--    /Karl-uid/`
  , now I would like that when my application displays posts that the publications of the users that we blocked does not appear .
to make the publications appear I use this code ( This code should take the uid of the person who posted the post and see if this uid is in our blocked list and if there is, it should not take the post)

```
 mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

ArrayList<PostClass> PostArray= new ArrayList<>();
Listview = new PostAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.itempost, PostArray );

mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "getPost: found post user: " + snapshot);
            PostClass post = snapshot.getValue(PostClass.class);

            DatabaseReference blockDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("BlockedUsers").child("UsersIBlocked").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
            blockDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (!dataSnapshot.child(post.getuid).exists()){
                        PostArray.add(post);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        Collections.reverse(PostArray);

        Listview.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
    }
});
```

Post is the class that I use to receive the data on the publication, post.getuid gives me the uid of the person who published the publication

But nothing happens when I use this code, so if someone can help me thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Listview.notifyDataSetChanged();` whenever the data set of the list view has changed. Since you're loading data in a nested `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`, you should call it in the `onDataChange()` of that listener:

```
        blockDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.child(post.getuid).exists()){
                    PostArray.add(post);
                    Listview.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
            ...
```

Also note that it's a really bad practice to leave `onCancelled` empty, as it hides potential problems. The simplest implementation is:

```
public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { 
    throw databaseError.toException(); 
}
```

Comment: it doesnt work  , it shows me only one post when it should show my 7 .  it have 10 post in total and 3 are from users I blocked I should see 7 post and with your correction I only see one post